# SD Card not found when connected in debugging mode Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to take a picture with my android app and I have a Droid with version `4.0.4` which is connected to the USB with debugging mode on. I want to test my app, but when connected it sayd "`SD card not found. please insert SD card to take a photograph`". When disconnected I am able to take pictures. I do not understand why. Please help.

Comment: Please provide more info regarding the error.

Comment: Make sure when connected with USB that your mode is not set to USB Mass Storage. It mounts the SD card as a drive on your PC.

Comment: @KeatonGreve: That worked. you can post it as an answer and i will accept it :) thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting my comment as an answer (thanks Intern!):

Make sure when connected with USB that your mode is not set to USB Mass Storage. It mounts the SD card as a drive on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

@keatonGreve's comment worked. I was connected in USB Mass Storage mode.